Combine two dataframes with partially overlapping column values
Hi :) I want to combine two dataframes, I have been looking on this site in the hopes of getting an answer but I still could not figure it out.
My first dataframes looks like this (I put it as table because I am struggling with making fake data):
| Hit | Well| Protein |
| :---:| :--:| :------: |
|1|A1|alpha
|2|NaN|beta
|3|NaN|gamma
|1|A2|alpha
|2|NaN|beta
|3|NaN|delta
|1|A3|beta
|2|NaN|gamma
Picture of table since posting does not show intended table
Now I want to add the following dataframe:
|well|species|
|:--:|:---:|
|A1|Dog
|A2|Cat
|A3|Bird
Picture of table since posting does not show intended table
Where my expected outcome would be:
| Hit | Well| Protein | Species |
| :---:| :--:| :------: | :----: |
|1|A1|alpha|Dog
|2|NaN|beta |NaN
|3|NaN|gamma|NaN
|1|A2|alpha |Cat
|2|NaN|beta|NaN
|3|NaN|delta|NaN
|1|A3|beta|Bird
|2|NaN|gamma|NaN
Picture of table since posting does not show intended table
I tried using:
testing = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
tesnjee = df1.combine_first(df2)
tesin2= pd.merge(df1,df2, on='well')
flame = [df1,df2]
testin3 = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['well']), flame)

However, nothing comes close to my desired frame. I tried looking on this site (where I got these options from), but nothing works. Do I need to add something to one of these lines or am I looking in the wrong direction?

Here working well left join - instead you complete code use out = df1.merge(df2, on='well', how='left')

@jezrael Oh that is a simple solution thank you! I am going to read more about those how= for merging :)
